# CSS behaving abnormally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying this for one day but I am still not able to do it. I have created a new index page for my website. I have copied code from my previous homepage.

If you see the sliders on the left(first homepage) and on the right(new homepage). You could see that on the new homepage the sliders are behaving abnormally. I can't figure out in my CSS why is this happening.

I have tried this:

```html
<div id="testimonial">
  <div id="black_title">
    <h1>Bead X Testimonials</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
    <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 232px;">
      <ul class="slide_left" style="width: 415%; position: relative; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-288px, 0px, 0px);">
        <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 248px;" class="bx-clone">
          <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/73331040" width="258" height="207" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> <a href="#">The Bead X Difference</a>
        </li>
        <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 248px;">
          <img src="images/test_img.png"> <a href="#">The Bead X Difference</a>

        </li>
        <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 248px;">
          <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/73331040" width="258" height="207" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> <a href="#">The Bead X Difference</a>
        </li>
        <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 248px;" class="bx-clone">
          <img src="images/test_img.png"> <a href="#">The Bead X Difference</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bx-controls bx-has-pager">
      <div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
        <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="0" class="bx-pager-link active">1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="1" class="bx-pager-link">2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <!-- <p><span id="left-prev"></span> <span id="left-next"></span></p> -->
    <div id="left-prev">
      <a class="bx-prev" href=""><img src="images/slider_prev.png" height="25" width="25"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="left-next">
      <a class="bx-next" href=""><img src="images/slider_next.png" height="25" width="25"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="read_more"> <a href="#">View all</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By abnormally I mean, that the text below the images in the slider is getting overflown and the controls of the slider are messed up.

But the result is still weird. How to resolve this?

Comment: You don't actually say what the problem is. Define 'abnormally'.

Comment: @Utkanos I have updated it.

Comment: Better provide css code seperately from html and define your problem

Comment: @Dim_Ch I am using jquery bxslider

Comment: upon closer inspection of your sliders on the live page, it appears that they each have two sets of controls (one has class"bx-controls" and the other has the class "navigation). This is probably causing your issues.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are quite a few issues going on here that you will have to deal with.  First it looks like that "Wax Daddys Promise" pane is an image with at Width of 269px yet the column you are trying to align is 275px so it will not fill that area correctly to give you good lines.

The .testimonial class margins are all out of place.

```
#testimonial {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    height: 310px;
    background: white;
    border: 4px solid rgb(209, 209, 209);
    margin: 15px 2px 2px 17px;
}
```

You should use:

```
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
```

or better yet:

```
margin-top: 15px;
```

And that is just to give yourself a top buffer.  If you give the same to each of the testimonial classes or just use `class="testimonial"` on all of those you'll get the top separation.

That should help a bit.  In the future you may want to look into bootstrap, makes grid layout really easy without having to get deep with custom styling.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, can you please help out me with the other things? Please it's serious. :/

Comment: Unfortunately looking at your page you have allot of styles causing the problem.  It looks like a couple fixes are pointed out by JRulle, but you'll need to clean up your styling as best you can.  You'll keep running into these kind of issues.  It looks like a big issue is there is a margin property on `.navigation a` that pushed everything halfway across the element...  Sorry not to be more help but its all in your styles.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to do a bit of formatting to clean up the layout, but this should help you resolve some of the issues:

Modified CSS:

```
#read_more { float: right; }
.bx-next, .bx-prev { padding: 0px; }
#left-next, #left-prev { float: left; }
.bx-pager { padding: 0px; position: relative; top: 0; }
```

Also, add a clear fix after your #read_more and after your .bx-controls DIVs:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```